# Condensed font showing badly in Firefox

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, type1

I am using a slightly condensed version of Lucida Typewriter for code listings, obtained with the fontmap line

```
lbtn LucidaTypewriter "0.85 ExtendFont TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont"
    <texnansi.enc <lbtr.pfb
```

and an appropriate matching invocation of `afm2tfm`.

This works fine for most purposes, but displays badly in Firefox's built in PDF viewer, which shrinks the glyphs vertically as well as horizontally.  I wonder, is it possible with common tools to make a derived PFB file with the transformation built in?  The PDF viewer might make a better job with that.

(Don't say, "Don't use Firefox," because I am sharing the output with others, and you will need to tell it to them too.)

Comment: As I read the source code, pdfTeX is modifying the font matrix when it embeds a T1 font in its output with ExtendFont, so I can't see it would help to make a PFB with the matrix modified in advance.

Comment: I filed a bug report for Firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1539074

Comment: In case others encounter this problem, it seems to affect documents produced with pdfTeX, but not those produced using tex/dvips/ps2pdf.